# No funciona importar un modulo en Angular

Tags: typescript, web, component, frontend, angular13

1. Tengo el componente TitleComponent en el modulo Shared, con el componente exportado

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TemplateComponent,
    ContainerComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    TitleComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  exports: [
    TemplateComponent, 
    TitleComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

2. Tengo otro componente Dashboard en el modulo Dashboard, donde importo el modulo Shared

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DashboardRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

3. Pero no puedo visualizar el htlm Title en Dashboard, no sale error, simplemente no muestra nada

```html
<p>dashboard works!</p>
<app-title></app-title>
```

Comment: Ya checaste en la consola si hay algun error?

Comment: Hola Cristina, eso es lo extraño, no me da ningun error, sigue corriendo la aplicación, pero no muestra el componente que deseo :(

Comment: Ya probates con otro componente, que pasa si agregas uno diferente?